# API POST error: MongoDB & Ionic App

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, mongoose, ionic-framework

What I'm Trying to do: Connect my mongolab db to my ionic app. (I'd use Firebase but Firebase doesn't have text search, which I need).

I followed the example at (https://scotch.io/tutorials/creating-a-single-page-todo-app-with-node-and-angular) for some guidance.

However, I'm getting the error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found) http://localhost:8100/api/todos

Structure of my files:
-Project

```
+-www
+---js
------app.js
------server.js
------cordova.js
+-----controllers
+---css
+---img
+---lib
+---templates
```

I know that I'm probably missing something fundamental. I don't understand how my server.js is even loaded by ionic?

Here's a snippet (just the relevant parts) of my server.js

```
// set up ========================
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();                               // create our app w/ express
var mongoose = require('mongoose');                     // mongoose for mongodb
var morgan = require('morgan');             // log requests to the console (express4)
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');    // pull information from HTML POST (express4)
var methodOverride = require('method-override'); // simulate DELETE and PUT (express4)
var uriUtil = require('mongodb-uri');

// configuration =================

var mongodbUri = 'mongodb://<myusername>:<mypass>@ds036648.mongolab.com:36648/<mydb>';
var mongooseUri = uriUtil.formatMongoose(mongodbUri);
mongoose.connect(mongooseUri);     // connect to mongoDB database on modulus.io

// listen (start app with node server.js) ======================================
app.listen(8100);
console.log("App listening on port 8100");

// define model =================
var Todo = mongoose.model('Todo', {
    text : String
});

// create todo and send back all todos after creation
app.post('/api/todos', function(req, res) {

    // create a todo, information comes from AJAX request from Angular
    Todo.create({
        text : req.body.text,
        done : false
    }, function(err, todo) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        // get and return all the todos after you create another
        Todo.find(function(err, todos) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err)
            res.json(todos);
        });
    });

});
```

the html i'm using:

```
<!-- FORM TO CREATE TODOS -->
        <div id="todo-form" class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 text-center">
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">

                        <!-- BIND THIS VALUE TO formData.text IN ANGULAR -->
                        <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg text-center" placeholder="I want to buy a puppy that will love me forever" ng-model="formData.text">
                    </div>

                    <!-- createToDo() WILL CREATE NEW TODOS -->
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="createTodo()">Add</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

my controller:

```
angular.module('starter')
.controller('todosController', function($scope,$http) {

    $scope.formData = {};
    // when submitting the add form, send the text to the node API
    $scope.createTodo = function() {
        $http.post('/api/todos', $scope.formData)
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.formData = {}; // clear the form so our user is ready to enter another
                $scope.todos = data;
                console.log(data);
            })
            .error(function(data) {
                console.log('Error: ' + data);
            });
    };
```

Comment: you ionic server and your API server should be 2 differents servers, this line $http.post('/api/todos', $scope.formData) seems strange as you should request another server

Comment: also you are running server.js on node right or something similar?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your issue is here:

```
$http.post('/api/todos', $scope.formData)
```

It should point to a server: so it needs to be something like this:

```
$http.post('https://localhost:8100/api/todos', $scope.formData)
```

Comment: thanks for the great anwser but what about when i deploy my app to server then again i have to change the path from localhost:8100 to mywebsitename in each file?

Comment: It should point to your api path. So if you are running your server locally for testing it would be like above. If not then it should point to your server. So yes you will have to change it.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to run the node server on a port other than `8100` as ionic uses `8100` port. Write

```
app.listen(3000);
```

instead of

```
app.listen(8100);
```

Now for the api request use this

```
$http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/todos', $scope.formData)
```

But this time you will get an error

> no 'access-control-allow-origin' header is present on the requested resource.

This is because the browser is blocking it as it usually allows a request in the same origin for security reasons.So solution is to open chrome by disabling the security by using the following command in the **run window**

```
chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security
```